# How dump partial backup from large MySql database?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, database-restore

This topic is very critical because, maybe, don´t have an exactly answer. I have a 22Gb MySql database in production environment. But for test purpouse I need extract, for example, 2Gb from database and this extraction must be with all dependencies (key, Index, FK, etc). How can I perform this partial extraction in MySql Database?

Comment: Only "by hands". Dump the structure (without data) and restore into new database. Copy some (not all) records to the root table using `INSERT INTO new_db.root_table TABLE old_db.root_table LIMIT xxx`. Then copy dependent tables using `INSERT IGNORE` - only those records which are relative for copied into new root table will be copied. Then backup this new database and restore on another server. PS. If some triggers exists they must be restored after all data copied.

Comment: @Akina Hi. I appreciate your answer and understand the problem. But at this time a have a great quantitie of tables and will be very difficult use this strategy "by hand". For now I will try another form to extract the data and and if I don't get another way I will try your estrategy. Tks a lot for your response.

Comment: *have a great quantitie of tables and will be very difficult use this strategy "by hand"* Why? get parent-child data for all foreign keys in your database from INFORMATION_SCHEMA and build properly ordered tables list (moreover recursive CTE will do it automatically if you'll add `level` field).

Comment: @Akina Hi. Tks for your response. The true is I don´t have database skill to perform what you explained. How can I get an tutorial for to do that? For temporally solve I get 5000 first lines from sql export data with "head -n 5000 <sql_file> > temp.sql". With this temp file I will populate the database. But I know this is the wrong way!!!

Answer (score 1):

This query selects all tablenames from specified database and shows their level in foreign keys tree.

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte1 AS 
(
SELECT table_name, 
       referenced_table_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE table_schema = 'test'
  AND referenced_column_name IS NOT NULL
),
cte2 AS
(
SELECT t1.referenced_table_name name, 1 level
FROM cte1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
                 SELECT NULL
                 FROM cte1 t2
                 WHERE t1.referenced_table_name = t2.table_name
                 )
UNION ALL
SELECT cte1.table_name, cte2.level + 1
FROM cte1 
JOIN cte2 ON cte1.referenced_table_name = cte2.name
WHERE cte2.level <= (
                    SELECT COUNT(*)
                    FROM cte1
                    )
)
SELECT name, MIN(level) level
FROM cte2
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name, level;
```

When you re-create database structure or copy data from original database to its recreated copy you must process the tables in shown order.

When you delete tables you must do it in backward order.

In normal state **maximal `level` value cannot exceed the amount of tables**. But it is possible that there exists a referential ring in the database structure. In such case maximal `level` value will be larger than the amount of tables, and **the whole technique is not applicable**.

---

In your particular case you:

1. Execute this query (do not forget to replace `WHERE table_schema = 'test'` with your actual database name).
2. Create new database.
3. For each line in output (storing the order) execute the command

```
CREATE TABLE new_database.{name} LIKE old_database.{name} ;
```

4. For each line in output where `level = 1` execute command

```
INSERT INTO new_database.{name} 
SELECT * FROM old_database.{name} LIMIT {some_value};
```

`some_value` may be the same for all root tables or individual.

5. For each line in output where `level > 1` execute command

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO new_database.{name} 
SELECT * FROM old_database.{name} LIMIT {some_value};
```

6. Enjoy.

If the scheme contains triggers they must backed up separately and restored into new database as a last step.

Comment: Akina, Hi. It took me a while to understand how everything works. I have already put the result of the processing into production with my team. I will study more about these aspects of the database. It worked really well. Thanks for the step by step.

Answer (score 1):

With Jailer you can export data to an SQL script which can traverse foreign key constraints to include all data needed to maintain referential integrity.

https://github.com/Wisser/Jailer